# Firebase Firestore 'Map' storage size

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a map saved in a document in Firestore, for example:

```
aMap: {
  exampleKey1: 'value',
}
```

does that come to...

- 5 bytes, Map name
- 12 bytes, sum of each field name
- 6 bytes, sum of each field value

...Then according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size a 'Map' storage size is calculated the same as document size, which includes **32 additional bytes**, and document name adds an **extra 16 bytes**.

Do Maps incur theses additional bytes like documents do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs states:

> The size of the map calculated the same way as [document size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#document-size).

Meaning that you need to add those 32 additional bytes when you calculate the size of the content of a Map. However, the other 16 bytes should **not** be calculated. This is because those 16 bytes are referring to the document name and in this case, there is no document name, there is a Map name, which is calculated as the length of the name plus 1 byte. In your case, 5 bytes.

For Android, there is a library that can help you calculate the exact size of the document:

- [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document)