# Firebase Firestore nested map storage size calculation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How does nested-maps get stored in Firestore, and how are their size calculations determined?

Say, I create this:

```
/Users/index  (document name left, fields below)
activeMonths: {
  '2010': {
    '05': true,
    '09': true,
  },
  '2015': {
    '02': true,
  },
}
```

What would be the size of this in Firestore?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549638/firebase-firestore-map-storage-size), but it adds the question around nested maps. Specifically, does each of the year maps incur the 32 additional byte penalty?

My guess would be:

- (5+1)+(5+1)+16 for the /Users/index Document Name.
- (12+1)+32 for the name of the 'activeMonths' map name and 32 byte map penalty.
- 2*((4+1)+32) for the two year map names and 32 map byte penalty.
- 3*((2+1)+1) for the three month entries' name and boolean value.

If it is true that each 'node' in a nested map structure hits you with 32 bytes of storage, that makes this a pretty expensive way to store a lot of data!

I wish the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) has some more complex examples to answer these kind of questions up-front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to Firestore's data model, a [comparison between documents and maps](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/data-model#documents) is provided, which would look like the following:

```
doc:
  first : "Ada"
  last : "Lovelace"
  born : 1815

map:
  name :
    first : "Ada"
    last : "Lovelace"
  born : 1815
```

When creating a document/map, you can add fields to it, and you can select map to achieve a similar structure to the one above. The following is an example of a map of Firestore console:
[image: A map in Firestore]
As for the size of a map, the other [Stack post you referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61554636/11672169) addresses size in maps, and your calculation seems correct: you took into account that [each map is considered like a document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/storage-size#document-size), where its name, fields' string name, field values and 32 additional bytes were all taken into account.

Comment: Before I mark your answer as the correct one, can you confirm then that there is no difference between a 'top-level' map and a 'nested' map? That I could have moved the two 'year' maps up as direct fields of the document, leaving the 'activeMonths' map as an empty map, and all the size calculations would have stayed the same?

Comment: I believe that the storage size would remain the same considering that the `2010` and `2015` maps will still be considered as map fields, just not under the `activeMonths` map anymore. If you were to do that, you could remove the `activeMonths` map and save a little bit of storage (12+1+32 = 45 bytes), but  deciding on that would depend on a number of factors like your use case, whether you are planning on having other different fields under your document, etc.